# Animation only works with the "infinite" word

Tags: css

i am trying to set animation to an #Element, but animation is only working when I use "infinite" word:

```
animation: AnimationName 1s linear 0s infinite normal both !important;
```

it does not work when I use a number instead of "infinite"

I want to play only one time the animation.
I have tried with the next code too:

```
#Element
 {
  animation-name: ANIMATION !important;
  animation-duration: .5s !important;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite !important;
 }

@-moz-keyframes ANIMATION {
  0%   { background: GREEN; }
  100% { background: RED; }
}
@keyframes ANIMATION {
  0%   { background: RED; }
  100% { background: GREEN; }
}
```

I use it on Firefox Nightly 22.0a1 (2013-03-23)

Comment: make a jsfiddle to replicate the issue and let us have a look on it.

Comment: Can you remove `!important` from your `#Element` and try again? Also, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-duration) example.